# Python: Setting up 2 scheduled tasks with variable times

Tags: python, multithreading, datetime, cron, scheduled-tasks

As I have written a few times before here, I am writing a programme to archive user-specified files in a certain time interval. The user also specifies when these files shall be deleted. Hence each file has a different archive and delete time interval associated with it.
I have written pretty much everything, including extracting the timings for each file in the list and working out when the next archive/delete time would be (relevant to the *current* time).
I am struggling with putting it all together, i.e. with actually scheduling these two processes (archive and delete archive) for each file with its individual time intervals. I guess these two functions have to be running in the background, but only execute when the clock strikes the required time.
I have looked into scheduler, timeloop, threading.Timer, but I don't see how I can set a different time interval for each file in the list, and make it run for both archive and delete processes without interfering. I came across the concept of 'cron jobs' - can anyone let me know if this might be on the right track? I'm just looking for some ideas from more experienced programmers for what I might be missing/what I should look into to get me on the right track.

Comment: The normal way to do this with cron jobs (which can be appropriate - if you don't have stringent real-time requirements) is to let the cron-job handle all outstanding tasks that are past-due and mark them as handled. This give you a delay from when the task is due until the cron job runs.

Comment: That's quite a dense post (no paragraphs, just a wall of text), which makes it hard to read. You are correct that it sounds like a cron job (it's easier to google that and work through than me pick a tutorial I haven't verified), but this will only work on linux. You could also use [Apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) but I think it would be better for the system to call your script in this case

Comment: Thank you for the responses, the formatting is annoying, stackoverflow reformats my responses into a wall of text by removing the new paragraphs I make, not sure how to go around that :( Re: the question, I'm on Windows so I guess I will seek another alternative, apparently scheduler is the way to go. Once the programme is finished, it will be an .exe file that the user will call, if that helps in any way.